# 61010-1 Clearance Distance from PCBA to Enclosure Wall

Tags: clearance

I am having some difficulty regarding the interpretation of 61010-1:2010 with regards to spacings. I think this is more of high level question/s at this point.

## Summary of Problem

### Scenario

I am placing a circuit board (PCBA) mounted on standoff in a metal enclosure which will be used in the US.  There are other components, but I just to keep the focus on the problem at hand.  The board will receive 120VAC input power (L, N, Earth) thru a cable gland in the enclosure, and the conductors will terminate to the PCBA by using a plug/receptacle near the edge of the PCBA.  The PCBA contains an AC/DC converter on board.   MOV’s are on the PCBA for the incoming AC.  The 61010-1:2010 standard is being applied.

### Problem to solve

How close can the edge of the PCBA (AC circuit points and even secondary DC circuit points) come to the enclosure wall?  I figure that solving for the AC side of things would take care of the DC side of things due to the difference in potential and the greater degree of clearance needed.

### Thought Process

Apply 6.7.2 “Insulation for mains circuits of overvoltage category II with a nominal supply voltage up to 300V.”  Basic Insulation.  Altitude not to exceed 2000 Meters.  PCB is Material Group 3B as CTI is 100 min by its spec so we either go with pollution degree 3 or conformal coat the PCBA and go with pollution degree 1 as pollution degree 2 is not allowed for Material Group 3B per this table.

### Confusion

Table 4 is confusing because it doesn’t say exactly what the clearance and creepage distances apply to:  Line to Earth, Line to Neutral, Line to secondary DC circuit points, etc.  Table 4 also applies to “Basic Insulation” which appears to relate to or include the insulation of the AC conductors going to the PCBA itself, and additionally, the fact that the “Printed wiring board material” column is present leads me to believe it the table applies to clearance and creepage between circuit points on the PCBA itself and again, it seems it would be independent of Basic Insulation (conductor insulation).  As an aside, where is conductor insulation treated within the standard, is it Solid Insulation?  It is not clear.  It would seem that using approved wire (UL 758 for example) and rated for the voltage, would take care of the wire requirement, but it seems the 61010-1 standard would cover that aspect too.

In the end, I cannot seem to achieve my first goal which is to determine the minimum distance that the PCBA; namely the AC circuit points can be to the enclosure wall (earth).  Similar logic/confusion could be used with regards to secondary circuits treatment within the standard.

The UL 508 standard has a table of Minimum acceptable spacings Table 37.1 which at least lays out spacings more clearly between points.
Note that there are no CTI values in Table 4 of the 2010 version of 61010-1 as are seen in a previous posting on the forum.

Comment: Wow, nice, extensively described question!

Comment: Regarding safety, if the AC connections on the PCB were a micron away from the metal enclosure, what would be the safety implication?

Comment: Andy, I would say that in terms of safety, if I'm not mistaken, there would not be an issue because the fuse would blow if there was an arc to the enclosure (earth) from a Line circuit point on the PCBA which could be a possibility as .1mm is less than .8mm which is the minimum clearance per 6.7.2.1:   "Minimum CLEARANCE for BASIC INSULATION, SUPPLEMENTARY INSULATION AND REINFORCED INSULATION for POLLUTION DEGREE 3 is .8mm."  The problem aside from safety would be that a NRTL could fail the assembly from a Listing standpoint because the clearance did not comply with the standard.

Comment: That would be my take on it too hence, 61010 might not be the best place to investigate that distance because, as far as I'm concerned the box would be earthed. Distance between DC output and box is also not an issue either. I'm saying all these things because 61010 is supposedly a safety spec. I've not read it in a millennia so I'm playing devil's advocate to try and see if there is anything creeping out of the woodwork that makes sense.

Comment: I cannot recall the detail, though I had to go through 61010 & 60079 multiple times. IIRC, Lines voltage and "high voltage" are handled differently. However, it still be the case, if the lines gets close to the "low voltage" circuitry on a PCB. Was it " for V > 60v,  required creepage 6mm" ?

Comment: Not sure.  The 60079-15 Type N protection and -11 Intrinsic Safety have their own tables for clearance and creepage and at the voltage you specify, the distance is likely more like you state; especially in-11.  The 61010-1 standard is a hefty standard itself I'll have to say.